# Finding the result after N clocks states

Tags: digital, flip-flop

[image]

This is the diagram of 5 D flip-flops. At first, EDCBA = 00000,  after 6 clock beats, EDCBA = ?

I drew the timeline values of E, D,C,B,A but got the wrong result. My teacher told me that the answer is EDCBA = 01111. but I got 11110. Please help me find the way to solve this exercise

Answer (score 0):

After the first cycle where not A = 1 is switched to E:  10000

After the second cycle where not A = 1 is switched to E, and E is switched to D:  11000

After the third cycle where not A = 1 is switched to E, and E is switched to D, and D is switched to C:  11100

After the forth cycle where not A = 1 is switched to E, and E is switched to D, D is switched to C, and C is switched to B:  11110

After the fifth cycle where not A = 1 is switched to E, and E is switched to D, D is switched to C, C is switched to B, and B is switched to A:  11111

After the sixth cycle where not A = 0 is switched to E, and E is switched to D, D is switched to C, C is switched to B, and B is switched to A:  11111